# How to restore IntelliJ threads panel?

Tags: intellij-idea

My threads panel looks like below, which I'm pretty sure is not the default appearance, but I can't figure out to restore it to default?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Restore Threads" button (green arrow) and/or "Restore layout" (blue arrow):
[image: restore buttons]
(taken from IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1.3 EAP)